# App crashes when switching to a new Activity/app page

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity, crash

My app crashes when I use use a menu button to switch to a new page and call a new Activity. I have programmed the same menu button/Activity in a few apps and never had a problem.

I have the following classes in my app:

1. SplashActivity.java
2. MainActivity.java
3. AboutUs.Java

I have tested the menu button with reopening the SplashActivity and it worked, so the error is not with the menu button and calling the function. I have also changed the contents of the AboutUs.java to have nothing but the imports and the R.id.about_us xml and it still didn't work which makes me think there were no errors within the page.

My LogCat Error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(667): 
ERROR: thread attach failed
08-04 12:07:13.039: 
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(675): 
ERROR: thread attach failed
08-04 12:07:19.119: 
ERROR/gralloc(68): [unregister] handle 0x3ea8d8 still locked (state=40000001)
08-04 12:07:23.489: 
ERROR/global(685): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
08-04 12:07:23.489: 
ERROR/global(685): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
08-04 12:07:23.489: 
ERROR/global(685):     at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
08-04 12:07:23.489: 
ERROR/global(685):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1379)
08-04 12:07:23.489: 
ERROR/global(685):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1344)
08-04 12:07:23.489: 
ERROR/global(685):     at com.peakmobiledesigns.kitchenunitconverter.SplashActivity$1.run(SplashActivity.java:28)
```

The menu java within the MainActivity that calls the AboutUs.java:

```
//menu starts here
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.feedback:
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("plain/text");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]"peakmobiledesigns@gmail.com"});
                startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    case R.id.about_us:
        startActivity(new Intent("com.peakmobiledesigns.kitchenunitconverter.ABOUTUS"));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//menu ends here
```

And this is what I have listed for that activity in the Android Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".AboutUs" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.peakmobiledesigns.kitchenunitconverter.ABOUTUS" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here is the Java for the splash activity:

package com.peakmobiledesigns.kitchenunitconverter;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
protected int _splashTime = 2000;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while ((waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    waited += 100;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            } finally {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        KitchenConvertor.class));
                stop();
            }
        }
    };
    splashTread.start();

}

}
```

Comment: Looks like the error is coming from SplashActivity or when you call SplashActivity, could you post that?

Comment: Could you post `SplashActivity`? Especially line 28

Comment: Specifically what is on line 28 of your `SplashActivity`

Comment: I added the SplashActivity. Does it look like there is a problem loading the KitchenConverter.class? When running the app, the splash activity seems to run fine and it then loads the KitchenConverter activity and it runs well until i hit the menu button. What kind of error here could cause the menu button on KitchenConvertor.java to crash when trying to go to AboutUs.java?

Comment: My mistake was this (a similar SO thread): https://stackoverflow.com/a/67309094/14598448.

Answer (score 2):

According to the code you posted, you're calling `Thread.stop()` which is a deprecated method and Android does not implement it.

In this case, there's no need for you to call `stop` at all. A `Thread` will stop itself when the block of code in the `run` method finishes. Remove the call to `stop` and your exception will go away.

If you do need to stop a `Thread` in the middle of its execution, you should instead use the `interrupt` method to let the Thread know that it should stop running. Your `Thread` code will need to call the `isInterrupted` method to know whether to stop running.

Comment: This error also appears when the new activity class extends from a incorrect type. In this case it is necessary to change the type of class for the new activity. In new Activity java file, you can change `extends Activity` statement to `extends FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 0):

I found out my mistake. On the Android Manifest, I had put the chunk of code identifying my AboutUs page outside of the application backets. It's weird how after days of staring at code, you finally see the one tiny mistake.

Thanks for everyone's help.